# Making widgets align similar to iOS

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I have the following layout set up in react with a flexbox:

[image]

Ideally I'd like them to align themselves left to right and cover the gaps - i.e. from the above example there are two gaps under the smaller boxes and two smaller boxes below them, would like those boxes to flyp up and fill in the last two spots.

Not sure what sort of algorithm or idea I'm looking for here, it also has to work for arbitrary boxes (though I can control for alimited range of sizes)

Comment: Perhaps Grid layout (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)?

Comment: [Masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) or something similar might help you here